# How to get display/text value of a cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a `duration` column, to which I programmatically insert values like `12:16` meaning **12 hours 16 minutes**. The values are displayed as `12:16`, but when I click on it the actual value is `12:16:00`.

Now, when I try to get the values(I need to sum all durations) using the following code

```
let values = statsSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for(let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < values.length; rowIndex++) {
  let duration = values[rowIndex];
}
```

I'm getting the Date object, which is `Sat Dec 30 1899 11:58:20 GMT+0144` for a column with display value `12:16`. How can I get text/display value of such cells instead of sheets automatically convert it to date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I do it.

```
function sumOfDurations() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,2,4);//four values in column B
  rg.setNumberFormat("#,##0.00");//number format
  const vA=rg.getValues();
  rg.setNumberFormat("[h]:mm:ss");//duration format
  var td=0;
  vA.forEach(function(r){
    td+=Number(r[0]);//sum each value as a number
  });
  sh.getRange('B5').setValue(td).setNumberFormat("[h]:mm:ss");//load final value and set duration format
  //var end="is near";
}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Little bit more cryptic than your comment with [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) :) I've used the method, and it worked fine for me, thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the country with such a weird time zone ?  Very nice answer by the way !

Comment: @Sergeinsas the sheet's timezone is GMT+02:00 Kiev, but the trickery here is that I'm using duration instead of date(which sheet expects). However, I'm still not sure why it's `Dec 30 1899`. Maybe it's just getting the farthest date kind of and trying to count from there?

Comment: Indeed ! The date/time object that have no date counts from the reference date. In JavaScript this date is 1899. Searching for explanation I found that there was a time offset correction for dates prior to 1930 for some regions... don't ask why, there is certainly a good reason. The script Cooper gave is brilliant because it doesn't care about all this and stays on the relative side of the calculation ! I like it a lot 